What is the landing requirement for Klein Vision AirCar?
The Klein Vision AirCar is said to require a runway of only 1,000 ft and a speed of only 75 mph for take off.
But I cannot find any information on its landing requirement such as:

Minimum runway length for landing under optimal condition
Wingspan clearance
Optimal angle of attack for landing
Minimum speed to prevent stalling
Typical speed when the wheels touch the ground and whether there is additional distance needed (with wings present) to reduce the speed to 75 mph.
Etc.

See April 2024 news article about its readiness to sold commercially.

Soberer evaluations and reports are in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_Vision_AirCar#References.
